# List of figures title prints in first page and contents of list of figures print in the next page

Tags: table-of-contents

List of figures title prints in first page and contents of list of figures print in the next page. This issue persists for List of Tables too. I used below lines to add list of tables and list of figures.

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, openany]{amsbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=subsection]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linktocpage, allcolors=black,%breaklinks{hyperref} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\input{UNTdissertation.sty}
\input{macros}
\newcommand\summaryname{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\newenvironment{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
{\begin{center} \bfseries{\summaryname} \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{} 
\author{} 
\maketitle
\include{copyright}
\include{acknowledgments}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\allowdisplaybreaks
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Output is shown below

[image]

Comment: You must be doing something for this non-standard behaviour to show. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: Echoing Werner, please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: You are using `amsbook` as your document class.  Please take a look at the comment I left on your other similar question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618392 , regarding the use of `tocbibind` with an AMS class.  I don't know enough about `tocbibind` to say for sure that it is causing *this* problem, but it's suspicious.